# Pulling List values and making a consolidated report

Tags: list, custom-list

I recently joined a new company and would like to automate their meeting notes and make a one pager every week to put them all together.

Let's say in a list per row corresponds to one person. Ex:
Name - Office - Task - Notes
Emily - New York -  Bought a new solution - ETA 2 weeks from now
Jordan - Ohio - Worked on the network upgrade - Completed
Sandra - Seattle -  Updated website - Awaiting for approval

The expected output is on this week every Tuesday based on the list:

> ```
> **Report Week XX** 
>
> **Table of Contents** 
> New York           Emily [Link to Anchor/Table]
> Ohio               Jordan [Link to Anchor/Table]
> Seattle            Sandra [Link to Anchor/Table]
>
> Name: Emily
> Task: Bought a new solution 
> Notes: ETA 2 Weeks
> Back to table of contents link
>
> Name: Jordan 
> Task: Worked on the network upgrade
> Notes: Completed
> Back to table of contents link
>
> Name: Sandra 
> Task: Updated website
> Notes:  Awaiting for approval
> Back to table of contents link
> ```

Any advice how to do so? What features I should look into Sharepoint?
Links and references be good.